# Nested generators not triggered properly

Tags: python, generator, spacy

New to python generators I want to nest them i.e. have generator A depend on the output of generator B (B is producing file paths, A is parsing the documents), but only the first file is read.

Here is a minimal sample (using i.e. TREC8all data)

```
import itertools
import spacy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
def iter_all_files(p):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
        for file in files:
            if not file.startswith('.'):
                print('using: ' + str(os.path.join(root, file)))
                yield os.path.join(root, file)


def gen_items(path):
    path = next(path)
    text_file = open(path, 'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text_file,'html.parser')
    for doc in soup.find_all("doc"):
        strdoc = doc.docno.string.strip()
        text_only = str(doc.find_all("text")[0])
        yield (strdoc, text_only)


file_counter = 0
g = iter_all_files("data/TREC8all/Adhoc")
gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(gen_items(g))
ids = (id_ for (id_, text) in gen1)
texts = (text for (id_, text) in gen2)
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)

for id_, doc in zip(ids, docs):
    file_counter += 1
file_counter
```

This will output only

```
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396002
Out[10]:
33
```

Where the following shows that certainly some more files are there to be parsed:

```
g = iter_all_files("data/TREC8all/Adhoc")
file_counter = 0
for file in g:
    file_counter += 1
    # print(file)
    for item in gen_items(g):
        item_counter += 1

print(item_counter)
file_counter
```

will return around 2000 files like

```
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396002
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396003
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396004
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396005
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396006
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396007
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396008
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396009
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396010
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396011
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396012
using: data/TREC8all/Adhoc/fbis/fb396013
```

So apparently my

```
g = iter_all_files("data/TREC8all/Adhoc")
gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(gen_items(g))
ids = (id_ for (id_, text) in gen1)
texts = (text for (id_, text) in gen2)
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)

for id_, doc in zip(ids, docs):
```

is not consuming the nested generator in the right way.

## Edit

a nesting with an outer for loop seems to work but is not nice. Is there a better way to formulate it?

```
g = iter_all_files("data/TREC8all/Adhoc")
for file in g:
    file_counter += 1
    # print(file)
    #for item in gen_items(g):
    gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(genFiles(g)
```

Comment: `path = next(path)` - why are you using an iterator there at all if you're only going to take the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but only the first file is read

Well, you only tell Python to read one file:

```
def gen_items(path):
    path = next(path)
    ...
```

If you wanted to go over all files, you need a loop.

```
def gen_items(paths):
    for path in paths:
        ...
```

Comment: So there is no more elegant way to nest generators?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler: In case you didn't notice the first time, the loop I'm telling you to use goes inside `gen_items`. If you want a generator to work over the items of another generator, it needs to loop. If you want to use a function that takes one item and apply it to the items yielded by `iter_all_files`, you want `map`.

Answer (score 0):

reviewed the code, I not know the mean of "nlp.pipe",try like this

```
#docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)
for id_, doc in zip(ids, texts ):
    file_counter += 1
file_counter
```

see the "file_counter",you will know the error .

Comment: Good idea. file_counter still is only 33.